# Exception in thread when clicking on node

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a JavaFX application with TreeView. When I click multiple times on a tree node I get this error stack:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.findMatchingStyles(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper.createStyleHelper(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.reapplyCss(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.impl_reapplyCSS(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.invalidatedScenes(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Node.setScenes(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent$1.onChanged(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.TrackableObservableList.lambda$new$19(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.chart.Axis.layoutChildren(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.chart.ValueAxis.layoutChildren(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.chart.XYChart.layoutChartChildren(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.chart.Chart$1.layoutChildren(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$31(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$401(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$146(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Into the error stack I see only internal JavaFX error. Can you give me some guide what might be the problem?

Comment: Do you have any listeners associated with the `TreeCell` or `TreeView`? Custom `TreeCell` implementations? What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Yes, I have listeners and custom TreeCell implementations. I use Java 8u60.

Comment: So do you get the same issue on the GA release (currently 8u45)? If so there is probably something wrong with your code (which you haven't shown). If not, it is possible there is a bug in the ea release of 8u60; you should create a minimal example demonstrating the bug and report it.

Comment: I get the same NPE on 8u45 and 8u60.

Comment: That moment, when you find an SO question with exactly the same problem but no answer. If only I could debug into StyleManager...

Comment: Do you only have that exception when you click multiple times or does it happen everytime you click on a node?

Comment: This is a issue fixed in JVM.